# show different divs on both show/hide condition

Tags: javascript, show-hide

i have searched a lot in SO. The text show/hide on click, worked only to show the div, when clicked on hide, it doesnt show another div.

I want something like this.

a text is displayed by defualt **SHOW** and div named **formula1** is displayed, when clicked on show, it hides the test **SHOW** and hides the previous div **formula1**  and text **HIDE** Appears with another div **Formula2**

The below only showed one div, but i want both divs to be showed on each when clicked.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> <== click Here
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">peek-a-boo</></div>
</body>
```

anybody please help

Comment: both DIV's??   There's only one in sample markup. Also what is `formula1` and `formula2` ?

Comment: @charlietfl     <div id="formula1">some text</div> <div id="formula2">some text</div>

Comment: explanation needs to be more complete along with enough html to represent issue in it's entirety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use JQUERY it will reduce the codes that are you writing. by using simple show() and hide() functions....
here is link [.show() jquery selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_show.asp) and [.hide() jquery selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp)

if you intersted in javascript then goto this URL [simple javascript show hide div](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascriptexamples/javascript-hide-div.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

worked for me

```
   <html>
<head>
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 
function hideDiv() { 
if (document.getElementById) { 
document.getElementById('back').style.display = 'none'; 
document.getElementById('sale').style.display = 'block'; 
} 
} 
function showDiv() { 
if (document.getElementById) { 
document.getElementById('back').style.display = 'block'; 
document.getElementById('sale').style.display = 'none'; 
} 
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:showDiv()">
<div id="sale"> <button onClick="javascript:showDiv()">Hide</button><br>Hide Button will be replaced with Show button</div>
<div id="back"><button onClick="javascript:hideDiv()">Show<br> </button><br>Show Button will be replaced with hide button</div>
</body>
</html>
```

on this script.. both the divs are hidden and show.. ex

when **Show** button is clicked, both **show** button and text ***Show Button will be replaced with hide button*** are replaced with **Hide** button and its text ***Hide Button will be replaced with Show button*** and vice versa